# Not able to add audio_service package. Need guidance

Tags: dart, flutter

I just want to add `audio_service` https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audio_service#-readme-tab- to my App.
For play audio. But didn't get success.

Basically, I'm iOS developer so don't know much about android setup.

Where I have to create, MainApplication and If I try to change  `AndroidManifest.xml` It give error message because `android:name=".MainApplication"`. How it possible to change     **android:name**. Flutter won't allow.

Please help me for android setup.

EDITED:

```
odChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat.addQueueItem(android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat, int)' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServicePlugin$ClientHandler.onMethodCall(AudioServicePlugin.java:392)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:88)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:202)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:329)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
E/MethodChannel#ryanheise.com/audioService( 8223):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
E/flutter ( 8223): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat.addQueueItem(android.support.v4.media.MediaDescriptionCompat, int)' on a null object reference, null)
E/flutter ( 8223): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter ( 8223): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:302:33)
E/flutter ( 8223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8223): #2      AudioService.addQueueItemAt (package:audio_service/audio_service.dart:481:10)
E/flutter ( 8223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8223): #3      _MyAppState.initializeAndroidPlayer (package:audio_player_service_example/main.dart:159:18)
E/flutter ( 8223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8223): #4      _MyAppState.initState (package:audio_player_service_example/main.dart:124:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3851:58)
E/flutter ( 8223): #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #7      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #8      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #9      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #10     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #11     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
E/flutter ( 8223): #13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #16     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #18     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #19     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #22     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #23     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #24     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
E/flutter ( 8223): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #32     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #33     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3869:11)
E/flutter ( 8223): #34     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
E/flutter ( 8223): #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #39     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #40     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #41     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/f
E/flutter ( 8223): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initPlayerQueue on channel audio_player_service)
E/flutter ( 8223): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:300:7)
E/flutter ( 8223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8223): #1      AudioPlayer.initPlayerQueue (package:audio_player_service/audio_player.dart:250:19)
E/flutter ( 8223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8223): #2      _MyAppState.initPlayer (package:audio_player_service_example/main.dart:148:23)
E/flutter ( 8223): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8223): #3      _MyAppState.initState (package:audio_player_service_example/main.dart:126:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3851:58)
E/flutter ( 8223): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
E/flutter ( 8223): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4881:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
E/flutter ( 8223): #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3869:11)
E/flutter ( 8223): #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
E/flutter ( 8223): #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #38     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3716:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2960:14)
E/flutter ( 8223): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2763:12)
E/flutter ( 8223): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3752:16)
E/flutter ( 8223): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3564:5)
E/flutter ( 8223): #44     ComponentElement._firs
```

Comment: There is hardly anything worse than mentioning an error message in a StackOverflow question but then not adding the exact and full error output to the question ;p

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer -- Please check edited and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MainApplication` class in Android studio. Take a look at these screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add this right before the `</application>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
    <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, But how can I create custom MainApplication ?

Answer (score 1):

I am attempting the same thing, and when I add the service and receiver tags to AndroidManifest.xml, I am getting an error, which might be the same problem you are having:

Class referenced in the manifest, com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService, was not found in the project or the libraries / Unresolved package 'audioservice'

And yes, I have audio_service as a dependency in my pubspec.yaml, and yes I did Pub Get.

I don't know why this error is happening, but I can't imagine that audio_service could run without this.